Related Rates vs Real Life - Boat/Dock Problem Curiosity
First ever post. I'm teaching my third year of Calculus 1 and something came up that I had not noticed my first two years. I gave a problem similar to this one: math.stackexchange.com/questions/2156970 and noticed something interesting in both the linked problem and my own. The boat is moving faster (in speed, i.e. absolute value) than the rope. My physics brain is not allowing this to be possible because if the rope was a velocity vector, than the speed of the boat would be a component of that vector in the horizontal direction and, thus, smaller in magnitude.
Is this just a case of Calc 1 problems being introductory? As in, students do these problems to understand the processes and maybe the real-life consequences are secondary?
Any insight as to why the boat would be going faster than the rope would be helpful. Thank you!

A nice first question, with a good reference to background material, and clear explanation of what confused you. Welcome!

If you’re worried about real-world constraints, revisit the ladder sliding down the wall related rates problem. In reality, when the top of the ladder gets to 2/3 of its original height, the ladder drops to the ground.

I can’t stand any of these “applications” in standard calculus texts.

"If the rope was a velocity vector" is a key phrase here...because it's not.
There's nothing in this situation that's actually moving in the direction
that the rope is pointing.
If you imagine for a moment that gravity is turned off, and the rope is cut right at the bow of the boat, then the cut-end of the rope would move towards the ring on the dock in the direction of the rope-segment at some speed $s$. And its shadow (assuming a sun directly overhead) would move across the water's surface at some speed $t$. And because of projections of vectors and components and a bunch of other words like that, we'd have $s < t$.
But in the actual situation, nothing is moving in the direction of the rope, so the boat's motion is not the projection (or "a component of") the motion of the rope or anything else.
Does that help at all?

Yes, the problem is unrealistic, but I would argue that it is unrealistic for different reasons than the ones you gave.
Imagine you have a slider attached to a straight rail in such a way that the slider can slide along the rail with very little friction. We now tie a string to the slider, put the other end of the string through a ring fixed to a position off to one side of the track, and pull on the other end of the string.
If there were no friction, as we pulled the string the slider would slide until the string made a right angle to the track, because then the attachment point of the string would be as close to the ring as possible.
In the real world, with friction, the slider may end up stopping at a point where the string is not quite perpendicular to the rail, because the more we pull on the string the more the sideways force on the slider creates friction against the rail and the small component of force along the direction of the rail is unable to overcome the friction.
But with a well-oiled slider on ball bearings (or some other low-friction bearing), the slider won't get stuck until the string makes a very large angle with the rail.
You're correct that the force on the slider in the direction along the rail is less than the force pulling on the string. But force is not velocity.
This is an example of mechanical advantage in reverse. Mechanical advantage is generally represented by showing that we can apply a small force over a long distance, which is then converted into work done by a large force over a small distance. In this case as the slider approaches the point on the rail nearest the ring, we have to apply a large force over a small distance (at a low velocity) in order to do the work of moving the slider by a small force over a large distance (at a high velocity).
In fact, the slider always moves faster than the rate at which we pull on the string, even when the angle between the string and rail is small. The difference just isn't as dramatic.

In the real-life case of the boat, however, we are not dealing with a slider on a rail.
A boat can move through the water slowly with very little resistance, but there is nothing except the boat's own weight to actually keep it in the water.
When the boat is much closer to the ring horizontally than vertically -- as it is in "Related Rates problem boat" -- the rope will pull the bow of the boat upward with more force than it pulls it forward.
The upward force can partly support the weight of the boat, causing it to ride higher in the water, and more importantly can cause the bow of the boat to pitch upward while the stern pitches downward. The closer to the dock the boat gets, the more force is raising the bow, and the higher the bow will get.
It follows that instead of following a straight path like the path of the slider on the rail, the bow of the boat will follow a path that curves upward toward the ring as it approaches the dock. As a result, the speed of the bow will not be as great as predicted when we assume the bow follows a straight path.
In fact, if you keep pulling on the rope at $0.2$ feet/second as stated in that problem, eventually the bow will be directly under the ring (horizontal distance zero) and rising at a rate of $0.2$ feet/second -- eventually lifting the boat entirely out of the water if the ring is high enough and we can pull the rope with enough force to keep it moving at that rate -- whereas the assumptions of the problem say the boat should approach infinite forward speed as the horizontal distance approaches zero.
In that sense, this is a highly unrealistic problem, and anyone who has hauled in enough boats can tell you why. The unrealistic -- indeed, absurdly nonsensical -- assumption is that the bow of a boat won't rise when you pull up on it.

Thank for this in-depth answer. It was very helpful!
